# httxt2dbm creates Perl files instead of .dbm file. Apache server does not "want" to work with those files

Tags: apache, perl, mod-rewrite

I tried to convert a simple mymap.txt file to mymap.dbm file to use in RewriteMap for RewriteRule. mymap.txt file is tested with and works perfectly. I was converting it with httxt2dbm apache functionality:

```
httxt2dbm -i mymap.txt -o mymap.dbm
```

And instead of creating one mymap.dbm file it creates two files looking like this:

- mymap.dbm.dir  (0 kb)
- mymap.dbm.pag  (1 kb / 1024b)

RewriteMap does not "want" to work with any of those files. I tried to rename mymap.dbm.pag to mymap.dbm and work with it. Did not work either.

Line from httpd.conf:

```
RewriteMap somemap "txt:C:\xampp\htdocs\htaccessTest1/mymap.dbm"
```

mymap.txt looks like this:

```
k1 http://localhost/htaccessTest1/keyw1.html

k2 http://localhost/htaccessTest1/keyw2.html

k3 http://localhost/htaccessTest1/keyw3.html

k4 http://localhost/htaccessTest1/keyw4.html
```

With .txt map I had zero problems.

How to force it to work?

Update1:

I tried force it to output DBM:

```
httxt2dbm -f DBM -i mymap.txt -o mymap.dbm
```

Error appeared:

```
Error: The requested DBM Format 'DBM' is not available.
```

How is this possible if that is what it meant to be?

Update2:

.pag file with following .dir files are Perl files.
But why does httxt2dbm create those files instead of .map file?

Comment: Having .dir and .pag files is normal for a dbm/ndbm/sdbm/etc. key/value store. Why do you think they're perl files?

Comment: @Shawn You are completely right. I did the mistake in RewriteMap syntax. Thank you very much. I will delete the question in couple hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteMap somemap "txt:C:\xampp\htdocs\htaccessTest1/mymap.dbm"
> ```

Notice the `txt`.

From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap):

> **txt**
> A plain text file containing space-separated key-value pairs, one per line. (Details ...)

> ...

> **dbm**
> Looks up an entry in a dbm file containing name, value pairs. Hash is constructed from a plain text file format using the httxt2dbm utility. (Details ...)

So if you're using a dbm map, you need to tell Apache that:

```
RewriteMap somemap "dbm:C:\xampp\htdocs\htaccessTest1/mymap.dbm"
```

---

Many dbm implementations use two files for storing data: a `.dir` file storing the hash table used for looking up keys, and a `.pag` file with the values. That part is normal. More [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm):

> Note that with some dbm types, more than one file is generated, with a common base name. For example, you may have two files named mapfile.map.dir and mapfile.map.pag. This is normal, and you need only use the base name mapfile.map in your RewriteMap directive.

Comment: many thanks as I mentioned in a comment above...Maybe you could help me with another puzzle I couldn't solve by now:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989683/rewritecond-request-filename-f-works-but-rewritecond-request-filename   I would really appreciate it. Kind regards.